# Как избежать ошибку при парсе строки в Long?

Tags: java, строки

Мне надо просетить данные отеля. Данные хранятся в файле txt, в таком виде:

```
1001,3,50.0,true,false,13.12.2017,Hotel{id=111111, country='Ukraine', city='Kiev', street='Hrehsatik', name='Sputnik'}
```

Я считываю файл построчно, разбиваю сплитом по запятым и присваиваю элемент массива объекту. Для того, чтобы просетить своему объекту отель, я сделал отдельный метод поиск отеля по его id. Id отеля лежит в шестой ячейке массива и когда я вставляю эту ячейку как параметр в метод поиска отеля, то выскакивает вот такая ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Hotel{id=111111"

Как мне это исправить ?
Вот часть моего кода:

```
public static Collection findRooms(Filter filter)throws Exception{
    if (filter == null)
        throw new BadRequestException("This filter - " + filter + " does not exist." );

    LinkedList<Room> rooms = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Room> roomsFinish = new LinkedList<>();

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(PATH_ROOM_DB))){
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] fields = line.split(",");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fields));

            Room room = new Room();
            room.setNumberOfGuests(Integer.parseInt(fields[1]));
            room.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(fields[2]));
            room.setBreakfastIncluded(Boolean.parseBoolean(fields[3]));
            room.setPetsAllowed(Boolean.parseBoolean(fields[4]));
            room.setDateAvailableFrom(format.parse(fields[5]));
            System.out.println(fields[6]);
            room.setHotel(findHotelById(Long.parseLong(fields[6])));
            rooms.add(room);

            int index = 0;
            for (Room el : rooms) {
                if (el.getNumberOfGuests() == filter.getNumberOfGuests() || el.getPrice() == filter.getPrice() || el.isBreakfastIncluded() == filter.isBreakfastIncluded()) {
                    if (el.isPetsAllowed() == filter.isPetsAllowed() || el.getDateAvailableFrom() == filter.getDateAvailableFrom()) {
                        roomsFinish.add(el);
                        System.out.println(el);
                       break;
                    }
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File does not exist");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("Reading from file " + PATH_ROOM_DB + " failed");
    }
    System.out.println(roomsFinish.size());
    return roomsFinish;
}
```

Comment: Сами же пишете, что делаете сплит по запятой. В результате получаете строку `Hotel{id=111111`. А `Long` парсится из строки только тогда, когда в этой строке лежит валидный `Long` и больше ничего.

Comment: Да, я уже понял. Удалил из этой строки буквы, оставил только цифровые символы и заработало.

Comment: Вопрос этот можно как-то удалить ?